# for loop variable not working

Tags: bash, shell

My script doesn't work. Variable `$Node` doesn't work. Please check below error.

```
Nodes=(SV41)
for Node in $Nodes
do
  NPAG1RESUCC=$((cat $logfile |awk '/$Node/{c=38} c-->0' | awk '/NPAG1RESUCC/{print $2}'))
done
```

Result error:

```
((cat ~/test.log |awk '/SV41/{c=38} c-->0' | awk '/NPAG1RESUCC/{print }')):division by 0 (error token is "~/test.log |awk '/SV41/{c=38} c-->0' | awk '/NPAG1RESUCC/{print }'))")
```

Comment: Your code has many additional errors. Maybe try http://shellcheck.net/ to get most of them fixed. It's not clear what you expect the first Awk script to produce, and generally you should get rid of at least one layer of parentheses.

Comment: Perhaps something like `for Node in 'SV41'; do awk -v node="$Node" '$0 ~ node /{c=38}; c-->0 && /NPAG1RESUCC/ { print $2 }' "$logfile"; done`